# Grails not mapping entities from hibernate.cfg.xml file

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am trying to create a sample project to demonstrate the use of `grails 5` with `gorm 7`.
Here I am trying to map hibernate entities using `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. The `hibernate.cfg.xml` file is placed under `grails-app/conf/` diectory.
The hibernate entity java classes are annotated with `javax.persistence.Entity` annotation.

But these entity classes are not mapped by grails and performing any `save, list` etc operations on these entities throws `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity` exception.

Please find the sample project [here](https://github.com/vishborade/grails5).

Comment: i saw thar you declared 2 annotations @Entity at User class, 1 from JPA and another from gorm. Erase this \@grails.gorm.annotation.Entity and try again ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try moving the hibernate.cfg file to *hibernate* folder or refer the path in application.yml https://docs.grails.org/3.0.x/guide/hibernate.html